# Can the running time be reduced to something lower than $O(d^4)$?

Tags: complexity-theory, shortest-path, dag

Imagine I have a weighted complete directed graph $G$ with $d$ vertices(so $d(d-1)$ edges) and I want to do the following:

1. Set $D$ to be a DAG with the same set of vertices but without any edges
2. sort the edge weights $c_{ji}$ of the original graph by size
3. From the biggest to the lowest edge weight: Add an edge $(j,i)$ to the DAG $D$ if we do not cause a cycle with it

Now I see two approaches to implement this.the first one is:

1. Set $D$ to be a DAG with the same set of vertices but without any edges
2. sort the edge weights $c_{ji}$ of the original graph by size
3. From the biggest to the lowest edge weight: Add an edge $(j,i)$ to the DAG $D$ if there is no path from $i$ to $j$

Now sorting can be neglected in complexity ( $O(d^2\log(d))$)

And number three is performed at most $d(d-1)$ times and to check if a path exists we can use BFS or DFS and the number of edges, unfortunately, can be as big as $d^2$ so we have $d^4$ in total

My second idea: Work with a reachability matrix and update the reachability matrix in every iteration of the loop...
But then updating the reachability matrix is again of complexity $d^2$ because if we set an edge from $j$ to $i$ then denoting the ancestors of $j$ by $k_1$ and the descendants of $i$ by $k_2$ we need to set $R(u,w)=1$, $R(u,i)=1$, $R(j,w)=1$ for any $u$ in $k_1$ and $w$ in $k_2$ ....
Assuming that in the worst case that each of $k_1$ and $k_2$ have $d/2-1$ vertices we get a complexity of $d^2$
That we need to update the reachability matrix more than $O(d)$ times can e.g. be seen by looking at bipartite graphs...
So I'm again stuck with the same complexity... Is there actually a more efficient solution?

Comment: The bottommost link in [this excellent answer to a similar question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97832/1984) promises to make adding edges to a DAG and checking for connectivity both amortised $O(d)$-time operations, bringing the overall complexity down to $O(d^3)$.

Comment: For undirected graphs, this algorithm is called Kruskal's algorithm and returns the minimum spanning tree.  But a different algorithm must be used for MSTs in directed graphs.  Is that what you're attempting to find, or do you really want the "almost MST" graph returned by this algorithm?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I am just reading the paper but if it is true what it says(what I of course assume it does) it seems like it indeed reduces the complexity to $O(d^3)$ - which is awesome... Thank you so much!

Comment: @BlueRaja - what do you mean? It is indeed similar to Kruskal but the algorithm also is: Kruskal does the following: Sart with the isolated graph and add the smallest edge if it is not already added; Now I do basically the same: Start with an isolated graph and add the edge of biggest value in case it does not create a cycle; But interesting is that the running time of Kruskal is only $O(E \log(V))$ which is better than $O(d^3)$ - so the question is if there is even more room for improvement

Comment: I suspect that this probably is not possible because: When I have Kruskal then I add $d-1$ edges to the spanning tree; This, however, is not valid here: Imagine I add an edge if and only if there is no path between the two vertices already; Then we can consider e.g. a bipartite graph; Imagine I have two disjunct sets of nodes $m_1$ and $m_2$, each having $d/2$ nodes; Then I can add any edge from $u$ to $v$ for $u$ in $m_1$ and $v$ in $m_2$, so I can add $d^2/4$ many edges - so a huge difference to Kruskal - thats why I think $O(d^3)$ is hard to beat - @j_random_hacker What do you think?

Comment: Glad it was helpful :) Indeed it seems that these "dynamic connectivity" problems are very difficult, and an ongoing area of research.  There is an even worse example of a cycle-free digraph: number all vertices from 1 to $n$, and create an edge $uv$ whenever $u > v$.

Comment: @Johannes This method does not necessarily produce a MST analogue for directed, weighted graphs, as the edgeweight of the resulting acyclic graph needn't be maximal. Are you sure you don't want it to be maximal?

Comment: First of all: Sorry for the many flaws I did when writing the previous comments: E.g. I mean of course: "It is indeed similar to Kruskal and the algorithm also is: Kruskal does the following: Sart with the isolated graph and add the smallest edge if it does not create a cycle" @j_random_hacker: I did not think of the most trivial solution: A complete DAG, how stupid of me;

Comment: @Sudix: You are right, it does not need to be maximal; If we want it to be maximal we end up with the Linear Ordering Problem which is known to be NP-hard (so you will anyway find no polynomial-time algorithm unless P=NP)

Comment: My (and @Sudix's) point was that you appear to be looking for the MST, but this algorithm only does that for undirected graphs.  If so, it's not NP-hard.  [Chu-Liu's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm) solves it in $O(d^3)$

Comment: You are talking about Optimum branching I assume... of course the solution I am talking about is not a solution for the optimal branching because in my case I can get a complete DAG whereas Optimum branching I have $d-1$ edges - but thank you very much for this remark